# How to analyse skin conductance in r studio?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, measurement, analysis

Anyone knows if skin condutance may be analised by some package in r studio?

I have a signal in txt.file and I need to analyse, however I dont have any tool or software to do this beyond the R.

Comment: You will probably need to roll-your-own, but R is a very good tool for doing that. The process probably starts with the read.table or read.csv functions? The default settings for these are often ok, you might want to check the 'sep' and 'skip' depending on what your txt looks like. Tidyverse is amazing for this kind of data wrangling, it's one of R's strengths. Some upfront time investment required though.

Comment: You could get more specific help from stackoverflow [r], but you will need to add some info to the question. To get help from them, at minimum you need to have a tiny toy data set (probably dput(head(mydataframe)) after you've figured out how you want to read the txt into R), and name the test you would like to apply to it. Iff you prep the question like that, the SO folks are phenomenal.

Comment: Just as a quick nitpick, you aren't analyzing anything in RStudio, but rather in R. RStudio is just an IDE. If you were using Notepad to write your code you would not ask how to analyze data with Notepad. That said, it's also unclear what level of help you are asking for. StackExchange is not a tutorial site that can explain all the steps for you, if you have a more specific question it might be answerable. For the approach it could be on topic here, or perhaps on CrossValidated; for programming it could be on topic at StackOverflow.